# High max connections is degrading performance with dbcp2

Tags: java, connection-pooling, apache-commons-dbcp

Have a `threadPool` set up with 8 threads interacting with the database, doing selects and inserts. Set up a DataSource by extending BasicDataSource and setting the maxactive to 30 and maxIdle to same.

My app works fine but, when I have a look at jvisualVM I see a lot of wait for a database connection,which is puzzling me since I have 8 threads at max which use shared JdbcTemplate

Database: Oracle 12cr2

How can I resolve this?

Tried setting `MaxIdle` to the same number as MaxActive and it doesn't make any difference, I still see the delays.

I thought maybe there's just one connection which might be being shared due to some misconfig with the jdbctemplate, so I set a breakpoint once after one of the threads acquired a connection and watched if other threads were being starved, but this was not the case, the operations continued but with the delays as seen previously.

dbcp2 config:

```
data = property.getProperty(Constants.DATABASE_INITIAL_SIZE);
if( data != null && data.isEmpty() == false )
    setInitialSize(Integer.parseInt(data));
else
    setInitialSize(10);

data = property.getProperty(Constants.DATABASE_MAX_ACTIVE);
if( data != null && data.isEmpty() == false )
    setMaxTotal(Integer.parseInt(data));
else
    setMaxTotal(20);

setMaxIdle(20);
```

```
java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
        at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
        - parking to wait for  <0x0000000540289128> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.LinkedBlockingDeque.takeFirst(LinkedBlockingDeque.java:590)
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:441)
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:362)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:134)
```

I see a lot of these in the threaddumps.

Comment: It usually means you aren't returning connections in a timely fashion. That you share a `JdbcTemplate` isn't directly relevant, as that will get a connection when needed. You really need to provide a [mre] that reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel did some tests, when the max number of execution thread is set to 4 or below I dont see the delays, as soon I as set it above or near 8 I start seeing the delays, is that indicative of something?

Comment: Why your thread pool is smaller than maxTotal connections? That's the bottleneck in my opinion.